# Glassfish v3 logging

Tags: log-files, glassfish

In Glassfish v2.1 I could look at my web-applications log all stdout and stderr in the glassfish server log ($GF_HOME/domains/domain1/logs/server.log). But I dont see the same in v3. Is there a setting that has to be turned or do applications now have to support their own logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasnt a Glassfish issue at all. Grails, our web application framework had some issues with logging to stdout.